# V - when memory gets freed

Tags: vlang

[V](https://vlang.io/) does have neither a manual memory release, nor a garbage collector (reference counting) nor an owner-based mechanism like Rust. How does it decide when to free memory?

Answer (score 5):

You can manually manage memory in V if you like by calling `C.malloc` and `C.free`.

V has experimental support for automatically freeing memory when it is no longer referenced. Use `v -autofree`, but there may be bugs for now. It allows some borrowing of owned memory when the reference doesn't escape. When it does escape, V will reference count the allocation.

It is influenced by Lobster:
https://aardappel.github.io/lobster/memory_management.html